# Is there anyone that can help me in finding an accurate dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, dataset

I need someone to suggest a dataset for palm trees, I am doing my computer vision project for detecting palm trees, but regarding to the short period I have I needed to have a ready made dataset for palms with high resolution! any suggestions?

Comment: google "high resolution palm tree dataset"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your best bet is to use ImageNet. It's a huge dataset that contains a lot of images and label categories. You can find a list of the categories contained and their corresponding codes [here](http://image-net.org/archive/words.txt). Palm trees have the code n12582231, so you can use [this link](http://www.image-net.org/api/text/imagenet.synset.geturls?wnid=n12582231) to access the URLs of the images which contain palm trees. You haven't stated what you're trying to do with respect to the palm trees (are you trying to localize them? Detect whether the image contains a palm tree? Identify different types?), but hopefully this gives you a good place to start. If you need more information with regards to using ImageNet, you should read through the [ImageNet API](http://image-net.org/download-API).

Edit: Based on the feedback that you are trying to count palm trees, then you might be able to use the bounding boxes included in ImageNet (more information [here](http://image-net.org/download-bboxes)). Using the code for palm trees, you can download the bounding boxes for the palm tree images from [this link](http://www.image-net.org/api/download/imagenet.bbox.synset?wnid=n12582231). Unfortunately, these are just bounding boxes, not tight object masks, so that may not work for your purposes. However, the bounding boxes should be one per instance, so you should at least be able to use them to give you your count.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am trying do make a system that will detect and count palm trees